# PDO_mysql for mac

Tags: mysql, php, mac, mac-osx, pdo

Has anybody gotten PDO_mysql working on the default PHP installation on a mac? It works with MAMP but that's inconvenient.

I'm developing for Zend Framework and mysql, and Zend_db uses PDO. The default php doesn't come with PDO_mysql.

Comment: Yes, but I can't remember how... it took about a day of playing around though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get it working with the default PHP on the Mac.  I had to install both MySQL and PHP from [macports](http://www.macports.org/).

PS: `Zend_Db` also has database adapters for PHP's ext/mysqli.  Your choice.  Zend_Db is not limited to PDO adapters.

Comment: Ah, I guess if I'd read a bit further in the docs I would have figured out I can use mysqli. That seems like it should do the trick!